# Backup kvm Virtual Machine with lvm

Tags: debian, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, lvm

I'm new to virtualization and have been searching for a while for a flexible disk format for setting up a kvm VM, after some reading i decided to go with lvm. And did set up the disk and the Partitions as lvm (so basically lvm inside lvm).

My Question is what is in your experience a good way or maybe a good script to backup the VM while they are running. 
i.e. if the Host Server stops working for any reason, i just mount the backed up VMs from the backup Server to a new Host and just start them.

The Host i'm running the VMs on is debian Jessie with cli, no graphical interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a drop-in replacement, with minimal downtime, you had to copy the entire virtual disks on another, similar hosts.

Basically, you must:

- snapshot the host's LVs
- copy the virtual disks on another similar host
- copy the virtual machine definition files (.xml) to the other host

If your virtual disks are normal image files, you can copy them using a multitude of tools (rsync, scp, ftp, ecc), while if you are Logical Volumes you need a lower-level tool (as dd or ddrescue).